# Using Structured Filetypes as Databases

Tags: xml, json, csv, terminology

In having a debate with a coworker it was posed that a flat file, in this case a CSV, could be considered a database. This would include XML and JSON as well. I'm interested in differing views on this.

Comment: Any organized collection of data is a database.

Comment: I am actually on the side that these filetypes can serve as databases. My coworker noted from your comment that a book is an organized collection of data. I think he's stretching a bit here.

Comment: @LJKims If you want to think of a book as a collection of pages, have at it. They even have self-contained indexes. The fact that computers don't store data on books with ink and whiteout is more of an implementation detail than a theoretical problem.

Comment: A book is a database, of course, and pretty advanced at that. It not only stores data permanently but also allows efficient random access to them (unlike some computer-enabled databases, such as VSAM files, for example). May be your colleague means "database management systems" when he says "databases"?

Comment: I don't see how a book is "structured" to the extent that it allows "efficient" access to any particular piece of data which it may contain. In order to find any specific word or phrase either the entire book would have to be searched or one would already have to have intimate knowledge of the contents of the book. The index only allows us to quickly find a chapter (usually). In this case the chapter would be analogous to a database field and would be it's smallest data component.

Comment: Indices in my books point to pages. Your paper-based database is due for upgrade.

Comment: You are correct. I was thinking of a TOC at that moment.

Comment: IBM made a product out of this approach.  You may have heard of it; it's called "[DB2](https://bytes.com/topic/db2/answers/185073-difference-between-file-table)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have to say, resoundingly, that your co-worker is correct and you are not. dBASE (.dbf) is a great example of a flat file database--which has been used for 35 years or so. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.dbf

Even RDBMS like SQL use simple 8kb pages for storing data. The tools we use to access the data makes it look more complex, but in reality it's stored in a very simple structure. Using hints, you can even have SSMS display these pages of data right in the output window.

By going by the simple definition of the database, it's a structured collection of data. CSV, XML, JSON, DBF all meet this definition.

Comment: Thanks for that feedback. I think that I may have poorly worded my question because it is actually I that believes that these files CAN serve as databases.

Answer (score 1):

@Mustaccio is right

> Any organized collection of data is a database. – mustaccio 1 hour ago

In fact, a CSV can even be queried by SQL directly with a Foreign Data Wrapper using `CREATE FOREIGN TABLE`. For an example, see PostgreSQL [`file_fdw`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/file-fdw.html) and the standardized command [`CREATE FOREIGN TABLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/sql-createforeigntable.html).

XML, JSON, CSV are all flat file databases.

While wikipedia accepts "Flat file database" in the context of a binary file, I would reject that. At the point it's binary you may as well be talking about a block mounted loopback as a file system.

Comment: I completely agree with this answer. However, while searching the internets on this topic it is rarely stated so matter-of-factly. Do you know of any reputable sources that would back this conclusion?